# How to save the output list from a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I have lists named `dat` and `res` with 33 datasets each. Iam running global minimum variance portfolios with a `for loop` like this:

```
for(i in dat) {
N <- ncol(i)
Amat <- t(rbind( rep(1,N), diag(rep(1,N)), diag(rep(-1,N))))
bvec <- c(1 , rep(0,N), rep(-0.15,N))
Dmat <- cov.shrink(i) #from tawny package 
dvec <- rep(0,N)
mvw <- solve.QP( Dmat, dvec, Amat, bvec, meq = 1 )$solution #from quadprog package
names(mvw) = colnames(i)
}
```

Its working, but saves only the last iteration of course. I dont know how to save them all. I need to save all the 33 `mvw` results in a list. How can I do it?

After that, i have to evaluate the results of `mvw` with the equivalent `res`datasets:

`mvwreturns = res%*%matrix(mvw,ncol=1)`

This command give me the portfolio returs evaluated for each period. Each `mvw` data matches with one `res` dataset. How can I do this? Iam wondering if I have to run another `for loop`.

Any help is appreciated. Sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

Initiate an empty list mvw before the loop. Then add each dataset as a new element in the list:

```
mvw <- NULL #initiate list
counter <- 1
for(i in dat ) { 
N <- ncol(i)
Amat <- t(rbind( rep(1,N), diag(rep(1,N)), diag(rep(-1,N))))
bvec <- c(1 , rep(0,N), rep(-0.15,N))
Dmat <- cov.shrink(i) #from tawny package 
dvec <- rep(0,N)
mvw[[counter]] <- solve.QP( Dmat, dvec, Amat, bvec, meq = 1 )$solution) #from quadprog package
#for each iteration mvw will be stored as the i-th element in a list
names(mvw[[counter]]) = names(i)
counter <- counter + 1
}
```

Then just do another small loop, same way as before, to do what you want:

```
mvwreturns <- NULL
for ( i in 1:length(mvw) {
      mvwreturns[i] = res[i]%*%matrix(mvw[i],ncol=1)
}
```

Sorry, I do not have any data to run your script but you get the idea.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Man! Thanks a lot for teaching me These stuff! I really liked that! And again , sorry for my poor Inglês and most of all sorry for  your time!

Comment: That is absolutely fine :). Don't worry about it, it's my pleasure. It makes me happy to help. And I think your English is great, I was able to get everything. Have fun!

Comment: Thank you! I still have 2 or 3 steps to accomplish yet! I will try hard, but if I get stuck I think I´ll need some extra help!! LOL

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a for-loop, check out `mapply`. Save the code you want to run over each entry into a function that returns mvw, push `dat` and `res` into a mapply call with said function, and it should split out a list of the result set for each element from `dat` and `res`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just didnt get what you are suggesting. I dont have such experience in R. Tks anyway.